# Vue Js Element UI how to render array object in table column

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vue-component, element-ui

For my **Vue Js Element UI** code, I want to display/traverse the array data in `el-table-column` but it's not rendering. String data is showing correctly only issue with the array.  I have tried by putting the static data in `data() return` method also but it's not working for me. Please check below code what I have tried,

> HTML

```
<el-table :data="tableData" style="width: 100%">

    <el-table-column prop="module" label="Module">
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column prop="status" label="Status">
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column prop="downloadfiles" label="Download Files"
                     v-for="(download,index) in tableData[0].downloadfiles[0]">
      <el-table-column label="File" :prop="download.file"></el-table-column>
      <el-table-column label="Path" :prop="JSON.stringify({download, property:'path'})"></el-table-column>
    </el-table-column>
  </el-table>
```

> Script

```
data () {
    return {
      tableData: [{
        "module": 'Order',
        "status": "Ok",

        "downloadfiles":
          [{
            "file": "test_20210406080352.zip",
            "path": "/opt/var/log/download/"
          },
            {
              "file": "New_20210406080352.zip",
              "path": "/opt/var/log/download/"
            }]
      }],
    }
  }
```

I have tried to parse download node data in 2 ways but both the solution not working for me. Please help me how to traverse the array object in `el-table-column`.

Comment: Hi, You can look at this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63099065/vue-js-element-ui-el-table-v-for-lost-the-last-item

Comment: @YashMaheshwari I have checked this solution but its not working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting first item in `downloadfiles` array here `tableData[0].downloadfiles[0]` and you shouldn't.

It works like this:

```
  <el-table-column
    prop="downloadfiles"
    label="Download Files"
    v-for="(d, i) in tableData[0].downloadfiles" 
    :key="i"
  >
    <el-table-column label="File">
      {{ d.file }}
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column label="Path">
      {{ d.path }}
    </el-table-column>
  </el-table-column>
```

Full example [here](https://codepen.io/jakob_/pen/YzNEgXM)

If you don't need to use subcolumns then solution would be to use scoped slot in table column.

For example:

```
  <el-table-column label="Download Files">
    <template slot-scope="props">
      <div
        v-for="(f, i) in props.row.downloadfiles"
        :key="i"
      >
        <el-link
          :href="f.path + f.file"
          icon="el-icon-download"
          type="primary"
        >
          {{f.file}}
        </el-link>
      </div>
    </template>
  </el-table-column>
```

Full example [here](https://codepen.io/jakob_/pen/OJWOqZR)

Comment: Thanks,  this solution works for me. Accepting this as answer :)